# How to ignore a failed CompletableFuture call when multiple Async calls are made in Java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, exception

I want to consume three REST service parallel calls in Java and my code is as below:

```
private CompletableFuture < EmployeesListResponse > makeAsyncCall(Request request) {
 return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
  () -> {
   try {
    LOGGER.warn("- - - - - Employees Service async call - - - - -");
    return serviceObj.findServiceImpl(request);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.warn("service async call failed...", e);
   }
   return null;
  }, asyncExecutor).handle((res, ex) -> {
  LOGGER.warn("Exceptionally...", ex.toString(), res.toString());
  return new EmployeesListResponse();
 });
}

CompletableFuture < EmployeesListResponse > asyncFirstCall = makeAsyncCall(request);
CompletableFuture < EmployeesListResponse > asyncSecondCall = makeAsyncCall(request);
CompletableFuture < EmployeesListResponse > asyncThirdCall = makeAsyncCall(request);

CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncFirstCall, asyncSecondCall, asyncThirdCall).join();
```

In the above code, I am making three calls and joining them using `CompletableFuture.allOf().join()`. This code is working perfectly fine when the service response is 200 OK for all the three calls.

If one call fails(`500 Internal Server Error or 404 Not Found`) and other two service calls are 200 OK, then the code is throwing exception and the entire API response is getting failed with an exception. In this case, i want to ignore one service call with exception and return success response from the other two calls.

How to handle to ignore an exception in this scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're trying to wait for all 3 futures to complete before finishing, but the `allOf` future returns immediately when a single one fails. Instead you can explicitly wait on each:

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> allFutures = Arrays.asList(asyncFirstCall, asyncSecondCall,
        asyncThirdCall);
// await completion of all futures
allFutures.forEach(future -> {
    try {
        future.join();
    } catch (CompletionException ex) {
        // handled below.
    }
});

if (allFutures.stream().filter(CompletableFuture::isCompletedExceptionally).count() > 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Multiple failures");
}

// else continue with your business logic...
```

Comment: thanks much! this has been really helpful in handling exceptions and getting partial responses from other successful calls. 
will there be any delay in response time of a REST web service when i wait for each future to join in the above forEach as mentioned ? because when i used allOf(), the response time was 6secs around and now it is 10secs approx. Can you please advise on this if it could be potential performance issue in the code ?

Comment: also is there a way that we can know the exception ex type is either HttpStatusException or ClientErrorException etc., to know if an error is 404 or 500. If i get all 500s then i have to throw a custom exception and if any one of them is 404 then i have to throw a different custom exception and if any one of them is 200, i will just continue as usual.

Comment: I would not expect a significant performance difference, possibly you're just seeing noise. Except of course in the failure case you were failing faster before. You can check the type of the underlying exception by looking at `ex.cause()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle the exception in try catch block as you are already handling **handle()** method. No matter you get the exception or not but this handle() method will execute every time. you just need to check if is there any exception if yes send default response as you want.

```
private CompletableFuture < EmployeesListResponse > makeAsyncCall(Request request) {
     return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
      () -> {
        LOGGER.warn("- - - - - Employees Service async call - - - - -");
        return serviceObj.findServiceImpl(request);
      }, asyncExecutor).handle((res, ex) -> {
          if (ex != null) {
              LOGGER.warn("Exceptionally...", ex);
              return "what ever default you want to return";
   //         or return new EmployeesListResponse();
            }
            return res;
     });
    }
```

Comment: Eclipse IDE is enforcing to surround return serviceObj.findServiceImpl(request); with try catch block even if we use .handle(), so i have used try catch and now removed .handle()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore, try like below

```
CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncFirstCall,asyncSecondCall);
allOf.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
    allOf.join();
});
```